# Eigenvalues of roots of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and set $\mathbf{B}:=\mathbf{A}^{m}$,
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a nonsingular matrix (formally $\mathbf{A}=\sqrt[m]{\mathbf{B}}$).
If we know the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{B}$,
what can we say about the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$?
It is obvious that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$,
then $\lambda^{m}$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{B}$.
But I need the reverse implication.
For instance, do we have the following relations?

- $\sigma(\mathbf{A})\subset\sqrt[m]{\sigma(\mathbf{B})}=\{\sqrt[m]{\omega}:\ \omega\in\sigma(\mathbf{B})\}$ (spectrum).
- $\rho(\mathbf{A})=\sqrt[m]{\rho(\mathbf{B})}=\sqrt[m]{\max\{|\omega|:\ \omega\in\sigma(\mathbf{B})\}}$ (spectral radius).

I would be very glad if you can give a reference for relations concerning the properties above.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $c$ is an eigenvalue of $B$,   $A^m(x)=B(x)=cx$. Consider the $U$ the vector subspace generated by $A^i(x), i=0,...,m-1$. The restriction of $A^m$ to $U$ is $cI$. It implies that the minimal polynomial of this restriction divides $X^m-c$.

Comment: So this proves $\sigma(\mathbf{A})=\sqrt[m]{\sigma(\mathbf{B})}$? Hence, the second one immediately follows...